# Fourier transform definition

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

There are the different definition of Fourier transform (i.e scaling constant or sign on the kernel). How can I show if the following is a correct Fourier transform pair:

$\hat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(t)e^{i\omega t}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

$f(t)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\hat{f}(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}\frac{dw}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

How I can show that this this is/or not a valid Fourier transform pair?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes, it is. But I prefer the signs of the exponents interchanged.  In order to see if they are weel defined you can see that the your first line implies the second one. Just do the computations on the right of the second line and observ that the result is $f(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

To get the constants exactly right in a particular choice of Fourier transform and inverse transform, I think there's no truly elementary heuristic... nor truly elementary proof... apart from remembering *one* correct pair, and then changing variables.

The immemorability of constants is illustrated, I think, by $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{2\pi i\xi x}\,dx=\delta(\xi)$, equivalent to many heuristics for Fourier inversion. Why the $2\pi$? I do not have any good rationalization for it.